# ruby on rails - automating form information and populating databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automation

I have created a ruby on rails application and would like to automate the creation of new model instances. I am currently using python scripts to log information on many machines and would like to find a way to send these log results to the rails server. I need to populate the forms with the contents of my logs in order to generate the associated database entries.

Is there an easy way to send HTTP Post requests that contain the log attributes I want in order to create these new model instances and database entries?

Answer (score 0):

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://example.com/search")

# Shortcut
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {"q" => "My query", "per_page" => "50"})
```

http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html